# Asignar combinacion de teclas mediante una funcion JS o JQuery a una tecla F

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Estoy haciendo un programa de cotizaciones con `PHP`.

Hay manera de asignar una combinación de teclas, a una de las teclas de funcion, por ejemplo F9, ya sea con JS o Jquery.

Quiero que al presionar la tecla F9, se ejecute mediante una funcion, la combinacion de teclas para escribir algun simbolo, por ejemplo el simbolo del diametro Ø.

Para obtener ese simbolo, se presionan las teclas ALT + 0216.
Anexo el codigo con jquery hotkeys, con el que hice la prueba pero no me funciona al querer agregarlo en un input tipo texto.

```
<div>
   <input type="text" id=">
</div

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('keydown','F9', function(){
                $('#resultado').text('Ø');
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Hago la aclaracion, de que agregue las librerias de jquery y jquery hotkeys.

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
   <input type="text" id="resultado">
</div>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        if (event.keyCode == 120) {
             $('#resultado').val($('#resultado').val() + 'Ø');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hola amigo, primero muchas gracias por tu ayuda, si me funciono tu solucion, pero al momento de presionar la tecla F9, me elimina el resto del contenido del texto en el input, dejando solo el simbolo.

Comment: Edité la respuesta, ahora lo agrega al final

Comment: Hola amigo, muchas gracias, por tu apoyo, si me funciona como lo pusiste.